# How to add DrowerListner

Tags: android-studio

This is showed in red color in my code. Please help me to solve this error.

```
package com.shafi.shafqat.listview;

import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class rawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    NavigationView navView;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    public void initNavDrawer() {
        navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.bikes:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bikes Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.accessories:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Accessories Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.contact:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact Us Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.login:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log In Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        View header = navView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView tv_email = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        tv_email.setText("skshafqat@gmail.com");
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View v) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(v);
            }
        };
        drawer.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

I tested the same code yesterday and it worked. But now when I wanted to combine this code with another module it highlights the following line in red.

```
drawer.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
```

When hover over it, it shows error

> cannot resolve method addDrawerListener(android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle).

Comment: Can you please add more lines of exception or log statements. Please add the code statements that is causing this problem. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: When i type this line then `addDrawerListener` showing in red color

Comment: Can you check if you have all the proper jars required on the classpath and imports are proper?

Comment: I will send you a screenshot of my code but how i send image in comment or give me your fb or whatsapp contact

Comment: You can add image with the question itself. That would not only help me, but others as well to help you.

Comment: Here is no option to add image

Comment: Can you please goto `edit` and use `ctrl+g` to add an image.

Comment: Now see all content in detail